# Javascript - Move file to another directory (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to copy a file and change the directory of that file

Here is my file location:

```
Test.zip -> Account/Images/
                   -account.png
                   -icon.png
                   -flag.png
                    .
                    .
```

When I use the script for extracting the files I want to have, just account.png file outside of Images folder  :

```
Account/
     - account.png
     - Images/ icon.png,flag.png
```

Here is my function

```
function processFiles(fileDir, outputDir, accountData) {

var fileDensities;
fileDensities.forEach(function(density) {
    var srcPath = path.join(fileDir, 'Account', output);
    if (!fs.existsSync(srcPath)) {
        console.log('Warning: image does not exist' + output);
        return;
    };
    var outputPath = path.join(outputDir, output);
    mkdirp.sync(outputPath);
    var srcFilenames = fs.readdirSync(srcPath);
    srcFilenames.forEach(function(filename) {

  });
 }
```

Right-now the output is :

```
    Account/Images/account.png,icon.png,flag.png
```

My question is how can I add account.png outside of Images folder

```
Account/
     - account.png
     - Images/ icon.png,flag.png
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `srcFilenames.forEach(function(filename) {`, check if the `filename` is `account.png` and then change the `outputPath` so that it doesn't contain the last part `Images/`.

You could avoid comparing with all of the filenames by removing the `account.png` file from the `srcFilenames` array and handling it separately.